# Inspect mysql docker container over ssh tunnel

Tags: ssh, docker, phpmyadmin

I have a Docker container that runs Mysql on a remote host.
I would like to inspect the Mysql database with Phpmyadmin over a ssh tunnel from my local host.
The container is inside the docker0 bridge with address 172.17.0.2 listening on port 3306.

I tried many times to do it without success.

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '3333';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false; 
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;
```

Here's an attemp with a double ssh tunnel:

`ssh -t -t -L3333:localhost:10000 remotehostip 'ssh -L10000:172.17.0.2:3306 localhost'`

Phpmyadmin configuration:

What I'm doing wrong?
I don't want to expose the Mysql port.

Thanks for answers!

Comment: What is the tunnels status after this command ? can u see both tunnels on both PC's ?, try telnet to localhost:3333 just to make sure u got reply. seperate concerns regarding ip-routing/ssh/application problem. i would also try mysql from the command line: >mysql -hlocalhost -P3333 -u[username] -p[password]